# Map Right Alt to Alt instead of AltGr

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have a Kinesis Advantage keyboard and I'm trying to make it so that my right and left <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys do the same thing. Currently the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key works as expected but the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key just allows me to type foreign characters.

I found the [following answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70931/how-to-set-right-alt-to-work-as-a-winsuper-key) to be very helpful, but I can't get similar results. Here's what I see when I type `xmodmap`:

```
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

In my case I don't have an `Alt_R` key mapped to any of my mod keys. When that's the case what should I do?

Comment: What does `xmodmap` show after you run `setxkbmap -option`?

Comment: The output of xmodmap doesn't change after executing `setxkbmap -option`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key send the `Alt_R` or `Meta_R` keysym, and to associate these keysyms with the Alt modifier (which for you is `mod1`). Put the following lines in your `.Xmodmap` file (assuming a PC keyboard):

```
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R
add Mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L Meta_R
```

That's if you want to configure this manually. There's probably an XKB option to do what you want — pick a US non-international layout, for example.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I added those two lines to the bottom of my `.Xmodmap` file and now my right alt key is finally doing what I want. I also tried just changing my keyboard config to `Generic 101-key PC` but that didn't fix it (using the `keyboard-configuration` package on Debian).

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched to KDE and found that you can do the same thing by using the *Keyboard* section in the System Settings. Simply choose the *Advanced* tab, expand the *Alt/Win key behavior* section and then choose *Alt and Meta are on Alt*.

Comment: Or *Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level* under *Key to choose 3rd level*.

Answer (score 0):

Check *Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level* under *Key to choose 3rd level* in the advanced keyboard settings, as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/539288/925128).